# Seg fault in my delete operation in c++

Tags: c++, dictionary, binary-search-tree

i am writing a code for a c++ assignment, it is a dictionary implementation using a binary search tree. My code compiles but when i try to "remove" i get a seg Fault. any ideas why did might be happening. Thanks

Here is my code

```
// this function calls the deleteNode function where the deletion is done
void BST::deleteContent(string *word)
{
    deleteNode(word, root);
}
// a helper fuuntion for the deletecontent function
//uses recursion to find the node to be deleted
void BST::deleteNode(const string *word, Node *&nodePtr)
{
    if(word < nodePtr->word)
        deleteNode(word, nodePtr->left);
    else if(word > nodePtr->word)
        deleteNode(word, nodePtr->right);
    else
        makeDeletion(nodePtr);
}
// a helper function for the deleteNode function
void BST::makeDeletion(Node *&nodePtr)
{
    Node *tempNodePtr;

    if(nodePtr == NULL)
        cout<< "cannot delete empty node. \n";
    // if node has no right child
    else if (nodePtr->right == NULL)
        {
            tempNodePtr = nodePtr;
            nodePtr = nodePtr->left; // reattach child
            delete tempNodePtr;
        }
    else if(nodePtr-> left == NULL)
        {
            tempNodePtr = nodePtr;
            nodePtr = nodePtr->right; // reattach child
            delete tempNodePtr;
        }
    // if node has 2 children
    else
        {
            tempNodePtr = nodePtr->right;
            while (tempNodePtr->left)
                tempNodePtr = tempNodePtr->left;
            tempNodePtr->left = nodePtr->left;
            tempNodePtr = nodePtr;
            nodePtr = nodePtr->right;
            delete tempNodePtr;
        }
}
```

**EDIT**:

Thank you all!! From your post i realised it was a good idea to check if the node was the last and had no children. I added this check in deleteNode

```
    if((nodePtr->left) && word < nodePtr->word)
    {
        do something
    }
```

i did the same for the right 
it worked and did not throw any errors or seg faults. Thanks so much!!!!

Comment: If the word being deleted isn't in the tree, you'll recurse into a null node. When you then try to do `nodePtr->word`, you'll be dereferencing a null pointer.

Comment: enable coredump and look at the backtrace. before deleting check for null and printout

Comment: In `makeDeletion`, you don't handle the case where BOTH the left and right children are null.

Comment: Pretty much need to rewrite your whole `makeDeletion` method. And state what you want it to do first so we're clear on that.

Comment: One of the most important programming skills is the art of debugging. This is a prime candidate for learning how to do it -- try stepping through the code, making sure each step executes the way you expect (and that the values of the variables are what you think they should be). When you find a mismatch between your mental model and what's actually happening, chances are that's where the bug is in the code (or at least, much closer to that point than to the segmentation fault that eventually results).

Answer (score 1):

**Case 1:**  Empty tree:

Suppose your your tree is empty: `root` will be `nullptr`.  So `deleteContent()` will call `deleteNode()` with argument `nullptr` for `nodePtr`.

The first thing you do there is compare `word` with `nodePtr->word` without first checking that `nodePtr` is  not`nullptr`.  THere you have a first case of segmenation fault !

**Case 2:**  Delete a word which is not in the tree:

In this case, `deleteNode()` will be called recursively until reaching a leaf node with no descendent.  As the searched word does not exist in the tree, it's either geater or lesser than nodePtr->word, but never equal.  `deleteNode()` will then call itself,  again passing 
argument `nullptr` for `nodePtr`, as in case 1.  Again you'll have a segmentation fault !

**Solution to case 1 and 2:** Control nullptr in deleteNode():

```
void BST::deleteNode(const string *word, Node *&nodePtr)
{
    if (nodePtr==nullptr) 
        cout << word << " not found in the tree\n";
    else if (word < nodePtr->word)
        ...   // the rest as in your original function 
}
```

`makeDeletion()` should now be called by `deleteNode()` if and only if `nodePtr` is not null and `word==nodePtr->word`. Get rid of the first if() which should no longer be true in any case.  May be replace it with an assert at to verify the invariant.

**Case 3:** Delete a word in the tree :

All the three cases seem to work (even leaf nodes with two null pointers), at least if I look at my drawing of your data structure.

However I'd suggest to **verify `Node::~Node()`**:  in all cases, you reattach the children and then you delete the old node (`temNodePtr`) without having set its children to `nullptr`.  So I wonder whether `~Node()`  just destroys the node without taking care of its children (then `makeDeletion()` should work)  or if its a recursive destructor,  deleteing the node and its children (then `makeDeletion()` would not work because, you would delete the nodes that you've just reattached, without noticing it, thus creating a seg.fault at the first occasion).

*By the way,  nullptr would perhap's be be more appropriate than NULL for pointers, even if NULL would work properly as well.*